# Grand Central Dispatch(GCD) based web framework?

Tags: web, clang, grand-central-dispatch, httpserver

Is it possible to make a web framework like Node.js (in the sense of non-blocking-async-friendliness) with help of Grand Central Dispatch's dispatch_* API? Since GCD, along with llvm and clang, is open sourced and has been or is being ported to both BSD and Linux, I am imagining whether it is even possible to construct such a framework from scratch.

Comment: I would love to see that. In contrast to node.js a framework based on GCD would benefit automatically from many cores.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.  In fact, creating higher-level frameworks like that (which implement async networking services, or full-on web frameworks) was one of the original design goals of GCD.  GCD provides the "plumbing" and you design higher-level APIs which hide the queues as implementation details; all you really need to expose are the block-taking APIs, assuming that blocks also map well into the API you have in mind (otherwise function ptr/context tuples are perfectly acceptable).